# sevenz_rust::decompress_file fails with "No such file or directory"

Tags: rust

I'm encountering an error and wanted to make sure I'm understanding how the `sevenz_rust::decompress_file` function should be used. This is my first rust program, so there may be some anti-patterns or obvious mistakes in this code.

[Here](https://github.com/dyz1990/sevenz-rust#usage) is how the package documentation describes how `decompress_file` should be used:

> Decompress source file "data/sample.7z" to dest path "data/sample"

```rs
sevenz_rust::decompress_file("data/sample.7z", "data/sample").expect("complete");
```

Right now I'm trying to decompress a file from a folder `data` that is adjacent to my `src` folder:

```rs
use std::fs;
use std::path::{Path, PathBuf};
use sevenz_rust::decompress_file;

fn get_full_path(filename: &str) -> Option<PathBuf> {
    let formatted_filename = format!("data/{}.7z", filename);
    let filepath = Path::new(&formatted_filename);
    fs::canonicalize(filepath).ok()
}

fn main() {
    let filename = "enwiki-20230201-pages-meta-history1.xml-p1p857";

    if let Some(path) = get_full_path(filename) {
        let target = path.with_extension("");
        
        println!("Result Path: {:?}", target);

        decompress_file(path, target).expect("complete");
    } else {
        println!("Failed to get full path.");
    }
}
```

And my folder structure is as follows:

```
package-name/
  data/
    enwiki-20230201-pages-meta-history1.xml-p1p857.7z
  src/
    main.rs
  Cargo.lock
  Cargo.toml
```

This program fails with an error saying that there is `No such file or directory` (when referring to the "dest/target" path) but my understanding is that the target can (should?) be created at runtime. Is there an issue with how the absolute path is being used?

```
Result Path: "/Users/megan/Documents/files/dev/package-name/data/enwiki-20230201-pages-meta-history1.xml-p1p857"
thread 'main' panicked at 'complete: Io(Os { code: 2, kind: NotFound, message: "No such file or directory" }, "/Users/megan/Documents/files/dev/package-name/data/enwiki-20230201-pages-meta-history1.xml-p1p857/")', src/main.rs:28:39
stack backtrace:
   0: rust_begin_unwind
             at /rustc/84c898d65adf2f39a5a98507f1fe0ce10a2b8dbc/library/std/src/panicking.rs:579:5
   1: core::panicking::panic_fmt
             at /rustc/84c898d65adf2f39a5a98507f1fe0ce10a2b8dbc/library/core/src/panicking.rs:64:14
   2: core::result::unwrap_failed
             at /rustc/84c898d65adf2f39a5a98507f1fe0ce10a2b8dbc/library/core/src/result.rs:1750:5
   3: core::result::Result<T,E>::expect
             at /rustc/84c898d65adf2f39a5a98507f1fe0ce10a2b8dbc/library/core/src/result.rs:1047:23
   4: wikiscan::main
             at ./src/main.rs:28:9
   5: core::ops::function::FnOnce::call_once
             at /rustc/84c898d65adf2f39a5a98507f1fe0ce10a2b8dbc/library/core/src/ops/function.rs:250:5
note: Some details are omitted, run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=full` for a verbose backtrace.
```

Comment: If you run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` and get a backtrace that would be helpful I think. I don't see anything obvious.

Comment: Thanks! I've gone ahead and added that output. I think I may try forking the  `sevenz-rust` repo and replicating my scenario with a test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem ended up being with the file itself: the compressed file was empty. After replacing the file with a new ".7z" file that contained content the code worked.